# apache htaccess check cookie redirect error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to implement functionality when user is being redirected to a login page depending on special cookie. I did the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^hehehe [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [NC,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

I want to be redirected to index page when cookie with name hehehe is present. But I get error 500. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly because the cookie is also present when trying to display the index page, and it is redirected again and again to the same page.

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^hehehe [NC]
RewriteRule !^$ / [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I change hehehe to _sd_c_i (with dashes), it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Try with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !_sd_c_i [NC,NE]`